# Derivative with respect to a sequence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, sequence, integer-sequence

I want `D[Subscript[a, k],Subscript[a,j]]` to return something like the Kronecker delta. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you don't instist on logical correctness.

```
      Subscript /: D[Subscript[a_, b_], Subscript[a_, c_]] := 
                   KroneckerDelta[b, c]
     Subscript /: D[ Subscript[a_, _], Subscript[b_, _]] := 0 /; a != b

      D[ Subscript[a,k], Subscript[a,j]]
       Subscript[\[Delta], j,k]

      D[ Subscript[a,k], Subscript[1,k]]
      0
```

Comment: I am not sure why  `Subscript[\[Delta], j,k]` appears in the code

Comment: Probably you are able to Trace the answer easily. Evaluation algorithm produces terms Derivatives[1,0][Subscript] and Derivative[0,1][Subscript] . The rest is printers professional secret.

Comment: I think I might have understood what you did to get the `Subscript[\[Delta], j,k]`. Maybe you used copy as then selected plain text rather than directly copy which would show `KroneckerDelta[j, k]`.